# grunt-include-replace workaround for recursive includes

Tags: replace, include, gruntjs

I'm just getting started with using grunt and I've installed `grunt-include-replace`

Now it does say quite clearly;

***WARNING: The task does not check for recursive includes.***

But does anyone know of a hacky way around this?

I've tried a number of things but not got anything working yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm thinking is there a way to install grunt-include-replace again but rename it to grunt-include-replace2 then run it as a separate task?

Comment: I've just tried adding grunt-bake to do the second half of the includes however I need to specify every file I want rather than just folder/*.html so although it works it'll add more time than it saves.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `https://github.com/vanetix/grunt-includes` instead.
I had the same problem, and although the config is a bit different and the default include syntax is different `include "_includefile.html"` and it does not support variables and globals as far as I know. It solves the recursion problem.

Answer (score 0):

This warning is misleading

The `WARNING: The task does not check for recursive includes` is actually referring to the script not checking for **circular** includes. It's warning that the plugin will not check for potential infinite loops, e.g.

> Where file 1 includes file 2 **and** file 2 includes file 1.

I very nearly went looking for another plugin for the same reason, but after trying it out, this plugin definitely does work with recursive includes, e.g.

> Where file 1 includes file 2 **and** file 2 includes file 3.